# Getting hanging indent and Word-style mixed number/letter lists in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-lists, word-wrap

I'd like to produce a list in HTML that looks like this:

```
1. Top level element
    a. Nested list item
        i. Even a third level!
    b. Another nested item
    c. A third nested item
2. Second top level element
```

By default HTML will use numbers for each level, so I'll get something like this:

```
1. Top level element
    1. Nested list item
        1. Even a third level!
...
```

I've managed to Frankenstein together a CSS style sheet that almost works with pieces of other answers:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li {
    list-style: none;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item
}
ol ol li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)". ";
}
ol ol ol li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman)". ";
}
```

The problem is that I don't get a hanging indent. I want:

```
1. Imagine that this is a really long
   line that gets wrapped.
```

but I get:

```
   1. Imagine that this is a really long
   line that gets wrapped.
```

[Here's a JSFiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7Y8/). Ideally I'd like an answer that works even once the list numbers are more than one digit long, and better yet if the numbers line up on the right:

```
 9. Foo
10. Bar
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this way too complicated.  Just change all your CSS to this.  The "hanging indent" and the numbers lining up the way you want are both default properties of lists.  All you want to do is change the style type.

```
ol {list-style-type:decimal;}
ol ol {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
ol ol ol {list-style-type:lower-roman;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rS7Y8/2/

Comment: Wow. So much for trying to Frankenstein together other bits of CSS (which I don't know). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using pseudo-elements you can position them.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9P5HN/1/)

```
ol li {
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:16px;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    position:absolute;
    left:-16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For hanging indents, you want to use the text-indent property with a negative value:

```
ol li {
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7Y8/1/)